# inputStreamReader won't recognise type JFileChooser

Tags: java, types, bufferedreader, streamreader

I have a variable, `inFileName` of type *JFileChooser*.

I've called this variable to the method *HexFinder* in class *checksumFinder*. It is to be used in the *inputStreamReader* inside a *BufferedReader*. (I'm using this line to call it)

```
cf.HexFinder(inFileName,null,null,null);
```

This is causing an error as the inputStreamReader will only accept variables of type String. (Here's my code for the BufferedReader)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(inFileName)));
```

Is there a way that I can get the inputStreamReader to read in *inFileName*? If not then how can I resolve this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to read a file chosen by a `JFileChooser` then you can do the following;

```
File file = inFileName.getSelectedFile();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Note that `FileReader` uses the default character encoding. You can manually specify the encoding like this;

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
```